# How to write an interface with base value and unknown amount of dynamic properties?

Tags: typescript

I have an object structure which could be as follows:

```
const myObj = {
  callback : ( val : boolean ) => concole.log( val ),
  string1  : 'foo',
  string2  : 'bar',
  string3  : 'bla',
  // eventually string4, string5 etc.
}
```

Is there a way to define an interface where the object has an optional property `callback` and optional properties `string` + `num`?

Like:

```
interface MyInterface {
  callback                                ?: ( val ?: boolean ) => void;
  [ ( must be "string" + num ) : string ] ?: string
}
```

So the only allowed props would be `callback` followed by `string1`, `string2` and so forth wit no limit like `string200`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want an array `Array<string>`?

Comment: @Liam yes I could use an array indeed but we have a method which already takes this object structure and I would prefer to keep the structure if possible.

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYkJgN), but the compiler will be pretty lenient about what it considers a "number" here, anything parseable as a number is accepted, so `"string3.14159"` or `"string1e-2"` or even `"string     -3.45e+54"` will work.  It also won't care if they are successive, so you can have `"string4"` with no `"string3"`.  Does all that work for your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the question to specify restrictions.  Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can now use template literal types as keys in index signatures:

```
interface MyInterface {
    callback?: (val?: boolean) => void;
    [key: `string${bigint}`]: string;
}
```

I've used `bigint` instead of `number` so only integers are allowed.

This allows keys like `string1` and `string123` but not `string` or `string1.2` (or the cases @jcalz showed ).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZc5BOAG2oCNEBrAfgC5kAKANxreToD2A6hDggAlMgC8APmRcBwACYBuUhWQBtRhHTsABgGcwUUAHMAJATrAzoMAF99AXXbHTIM2pIPSpJRAI1HBQKAgCIMbIAnQAVuwY2JCwiBDepDGxAHRUtAwIjBlxmgBE7uYAjCXO3pml5Z4VAEzVtcVlJpVZLTVFsfWdnq1AA)